# auto adjust and alignment of tds

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have two tr classes.

The view is:

[image]

I defined my css but seems I can not align it to make space between headlines equal.

I dont want do change my view with additional tags, just want to edit my existing tr's and td's.

My css:

```
td.style36 {
  vertical-align: center;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: none #000000;
  border-top: none #000000;
  border-left: none #000000;
  border-right: none #000000;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS';
  font-size: 10pt;
  background-color: #3B4E87;
}

td.style62 {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #C0C0C0 !important;
  border-top: none #000000;
  border-left: none #000000;
  border-right: none #000000;
  color: #000000;
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS';
  font-size: 10pt;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

And HTML:

```
<tr class="row17">
    <td class="column5 style36 s">DATE</td>
    <td class="column5 style36 s">TYPE</td>
</tr>
<tr class="row18">
   <td class="column0 style62 n">18/Dec/2019 16:12:52</td>
   <td class="column1 style62 null">credit</td>
   ...
</tr>
```

Comment: You could try `table-layout:fixed` on the table to make all the columns the same width but if the text is different lengths there is NO method of equalising the space between words such as you suggest

Comment: I have different tds in a table as a table is my whole page view so I need it just for specific columns as this two. @Paulie_D

Comment: Well as I said, there is NO method of equalising space between text in table headings.